# rails config mailer default url options not taking effect (development environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, server, localhost, host

I'm working on adjusting the url appearing in a mailer created with,

```
<%= controller_url %>
```

but when I change the default with the following command

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.com", :protocol => 'https', :subdomain => "www"}
```

the url remains unchanged as

http://localhost:8000/controller

What are some possible causes for this not working? I looked pretty thoroughly through my project folder for places where the host or subdomain might be defined, but found nothing.

EDIT:
It seems I needed to restart my server after making the changes.

Comment: I believe the default url is being implemented on production, which is the cause for the need to change. (splitting the :host and :subdomain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you trying but I can show my files to compare with yours.

So my development file is `/config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

and my production file is `/config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "https://example.com" } #=> Or https://www.example.com
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => ENV['USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'example.com',
    :address => 'smtp.example.net',
    :port => 321,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

and it's working perfectly.

Remember these:

- Development file is working only when a project is a development mode
- Production file is working only when a project is a production mode
- And make sure you restarted the server after change anything on related to configuration

You can check the logs while sending mail what's happening and for production run follow this command `rails server -e production`

Comment: Thanks. If you change the host: 'localhost' part in development, does it change your generated urls? From reading the rails guides, I would assume that it should, but it's not changing for me. It'd be helpful to have this information to determine if there is a setting someone else made in the project that is overriding this, or if it is the normal behavior.

Comment: @SamuelFrost Yes! it's changing I'm sure for over sure I just checked again and my logs showing `<a href="http://example:3000/login">Click here</a> to login`, here I just change host `example` and restarted the server. make sure restart the server after change anything on the configuration

Comment: Thanks, that helps narrow things down a bit! But I'm still puzzled as to why it's not working. I can only imagine there's either a gem doing something behind the scenes or something going on at an OS level.

Comment: Ahh, it was the restarting the server! I had assumed it was updating as I read that the development config file was reloaded at every request.

Comment: Great to hear it